# Comparing two source trees where files have been renamed and code moved around?

Tags: ide, diff, devtools

Does anyone know of any way I can get a visual diff of code in two source trees when some files have been renamed and some code split off to new files?  Is there any sort of diff tool that is smart enough to do this...to match up code blocks in different files? The code in question is Java, but I'm thinking that what the language is shouldn't matter.

I'm thinking there might be something like this available because I'm a PyCharm/IntelliJ user, and those IDEs often find and report duplicate code blocks in the same source tree.  It seems to me that this is a similar capability to what I'm looking for.

If there's no tool to automatically do this, but you have any advice as to how I can do this most efficiently with manual effort, I'd love to hear your thoughts. TIA!

Comment: You *might* have a fighting chance to do *some* of what you're looking for if both source trees are under Git, in distinct branches, and you used Git commands to rename them...  Hopefully, you're using *some* kind of version control...

Comment: @paulsm4 - that is indeed my situation. I have two Git branches that have a common commit back in late 2000.  But it's the splitting of code into different files that is the bigger issue than the simple renames.  Git can't have any clue as to those edits, right?